# Reading CSV files from a public S3 instance is slow for the RShiny app in my EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, shiny

I am building a web app that I am currently hosting in an EC2 instance. It is an RShiny app, and I have installed ShinyServer on my instance. Although I am considering switching over to a database (which would require me learning how to set up a database, and connecting it to my code), currently the app requires loading in 6 CSV files that I have saved in an S3 bucket. The files are public so i can read them in.

Here is two different ways to read the CSV files into the app:

```
library(RCurl) 
library(readr)

my.df <- read_csv('mycsvfile.csv')
myy.df <- read.csv(
    textConnection(
        getURL("https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/mycsvfile.csv")),
   sep=",", 
   header = TRUE, 
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The first method uses readr's read_csv function. I use this on my local machine, however since I don't have the CSV files in my EC2 instance, i cannot use it for my hosted app. The second method uses RCurl to grab the files from the S3 bucket.

My issue is this - reading locally takes <1 second, whereas grabbing from S3 takes ~7-10 seconds. For 6 CSV files, this issue adds up quickly. Other than creating a database on my EC2 instance, is there a quicker way for me to read the CSV files into my hosted app?

Thanks!

EDIT - I'm currently scp'ing the files into the instance. I'm probably going to set up a git repo that links between the instance and my local machine to get this to work better.

Comment: You don't need RCurl here. Just use readr directly, as it can read from a URL.